# Listen for event when user opens app switcher on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, background, nsnotifications

How can I listen for an event when a user opens the [app switcher](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202070) (the UI that comes up when a user double taps on the home button) on iOS.

I though [UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification) would fire, but it doesn't fire when I open the app switcher.  It only fires when I minimize the app by tapping the home button once.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
  self,
  selector: "onPause",
  name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification,
  object:nil)

func onPause() {
  //Not invoked when app switcher is opened
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should receive a `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` in that case. Your app is no longer the active app, but has not yet moved to the background.

If the user goes back to your app you'll get a `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` when the app becomes active again. If the user does swap to another app, or select the springboard, then you should get a `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification`.

Comment: Sorry, that should read "...another app has not yet moved to the foreground."

Comment: How about "the app has not yet moved to the background" ?